# Combination of values ​using dictionary or list

Tags: python, recursion, python-itertools

I'm trying to write a function that takes the values ​​in a list or dictionary and returns the combination of an approximate value. I adjusted the code found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-all-possible-pairs-with-given-sum/):

```
from itertools import takewhile, combinations, permutations, product

def findPairs(lst, K):
    for i in range(1,len(lst),1):
        print([pair for pair in combinations(lst, i) if sum(pair) >= K-0.01 and sum(pair) <= K+0.01])
```

When running this code with the parameters:

```
K = 1282.66
print(findPairs(lst, K))
```

I get the following response

```
[(263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.36), (263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.37)]
```

The combinations are correct and the pairs that were reported have been found. However, I wanted to go into a little more detail because on a daily basis I would have many pairs for the same price as the base would be much larger. I soon thought if I could use something like a list or dictionary, like this:

```
lst = [['A1',263.09], ['A2',883.58],['A3', 75.75], ['A4',29.88],['A5',30.36],['A6',30.37]['A7',590.72],['A8', 162.45], ['A9',47.25], ['A10',252.98], ['A11',69.57],['A12', 20.24]]
```

Getting the following response:

```
[(A1,A2, A3, A4,A5),(263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.36)], [(A1,A2, A3, A4,A6),(263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.37)]
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the question here exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def findPairs(lst, K):
    out = [
        comb
        for i in range(1, len(lst))
        for comb in combinations(lst, i)
        if (s := sum(v for _, v in comb)) >= K - 0.01 and s <= K + 0.01
    ]

    return [list(zip(*subl)) for subl in out]

lst = [
    ["A1", 263.09],
    ["A2", 883.58],
    ["A3", 75.75],
    ["A4", 29.88],
    ["A5", 30.36],
    ["A6", 30.37],
    ["A7", 590.72],
    ["A8", 162.45],
    ["A9", 47.25],
    ["A10", 252.98],
    ["A11", 69.57],
    ["A12", 20.24],
]

K = 1282.66
print(findPairs(lst, K))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), (263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.36)],
    [("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A6"), (263.09, 883.58, 75.75, 29.88, 30.37)],
]
```

Comment: Walrus? Ugh. Chaining! (Or abs.)

Comment: Also, one trick I like to use is to [use two](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZA7DsIwEERFS80BprQhQaFDiJwgDT1KYcCGlZJNZDtIcBUaGjgUpwEnEETBVPt5q1nN5V6f_KHi6_XWeBPPH4PRThsY4t1KkXWicD5CJhdDvMSq1C7CURWNdkhxplqMX4Rst1b7xjLWbRO05gC7vB-YyoJADKt4r8UsQqE5WEj5w3R3AQwO_SpoW5UbYuWpYife_5CM_jPdswHqmW9FBhliJNNkhmUK15Ti6GQoM0zacYvmXTjvjD5ZPQE) `combinations` in parallel, one for the names and one for the values. Then it's simply `sum(vs)`. Makes your solution about twice as fast.

Comment: Andrej Kesely, Simply sensational. Thank you very much